# If $\int f d\mu = 1$ with $\mu$ probability measure, then $f(x)=1$ for $f\mu$-a.e. $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f \colon X \to \mathbb R^+$ be a non negative, measurable function (w.r.t. a probability measure $\mu$ on $X$), with $\int f d\mu = 1$. 
From this it does **not** follow $f = 1$ $\mu$-a.e.

However, is it true that $f=1$ $\tilde{\mu}$-a.e., being $\tilde{\mu} := f\mu$?

I perfectly know this is a stupid question, but I have a terrible confusion in my mind and I cannot understand what is going on... 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \in (0, \tfrac{1}{2}), \\ 2, & x \in (\tfrac{1}{2},1) \end{cases}$$
then

$$\int_{(0,1)} f(x) \, dx = 1.$$

Since

$$\{f=1\} = \emptyset$$

it holds for any measure $\nu$ on $((0,1),\mathcal{B}((0,1))$ that

$$\nu(f=1)=0;$$

hence in particular

$$\tilde{\mu}(f=1)=0.$$

This shows that, in general, $f=1$ $\tilde{\mu}$-a.e. does not hold true.

Comment: Thanks, I am always stupid, that was easy.

Answer (score 2):

Nah: pick two distinct nonzero numbers whose average is 1, say $3/2$ and $1/2$. Take $X=\{ 0,1 \}$, $\mu$ the uniform measure on this set. Define $f(0),f(1)$ to be the two numbers you picked. Then $f$ is never 1 at all, but $\int f d \mu = 1$. And $f \mu$ assigns measure $3/2$ to $\{ 0 \}$ and $1/2$ to $\{ 1 \}$.

Comment: To complete this, you should note what is $f\mu$ in this case.  Since the OP never defined it, we have to know that notation somehow.

Answer (score 1):

For a continuous counterexample, consider $\mu$ to be the lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$, and take $f(x) = 2x$.

Comment: To complete this, you should note what is $f\mu$ in this case.  Since the OP never defined it, we have to know that notation somehow.

Comment: @GEdgar I think OP's second question is not well articulated --- the measure $\mu$ should be given in advance and fixed, then tried looking for $f$. Otherwise there should be two different $f$s, which is confusing. So I answered the first question only.